# How to check if an object exists

Tags: perl

I am trying to extract the domain part of a URL and I want to cover the case where the input is invalid.

```
 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use URI;
 use Data::Dumper;

 my $url = URI->new( "garbled" );
 # my $url = URI->new( "http://www.google.com/" ); # this works
 # print Dumper $url;
 print $url->host if defined($url->host) ;
```

Gives `Can't locate object method "host" via package "URI::_generic" at`

How can check if the URL was parsed correctly?

Comment: Depends on what exactly you're trying to do, but you could use e.g. `if ($url->scheme eq 'http' || $url->scheme eq 'https')`.

Comment: @melpomene thanks. Based on your comment, I presume I can rely on `$url->scheme` to figure out if it parsed properly. If I add ` (defined($url->scheme)` to your suggestion, it works fine. Any other edge case where this can fail? I am parse large file and don't want to fail in the middle.

Comment: consider `$uri->has_recognized_scheme` - check the docs for the (long) list of supported schemes. If you're only interested in http/https, you could either check the scheme after, or even use the regex provided in the module.

Comment: Another useful tool, especially for the question in your title (which btw does not fit your question body), is [Safe::Isa](https://metacpan.org/pod/Safe::Isa). [Here's a lightning talk by the author](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aCsUxfRksE) explaining how it works and what it can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the general case you can use `UNIVERSAL::can`

```
if (ref($url) && $url->can("host")) { ... }
```

or exception handling

```
eval { print $url->host };
if ($@) { warn "\$url wasn't what I thought it was" }
```

but in most cases you would want to drill down into the error and find the mismatch between your expectations and the program's behavior.

Comment: This is great. This is what I was after. Thank you!

Comment: This is wrong. It works only because the module cannot extract the *host* field from the URI unless it recognises the *scheme*. It is far better, as [**bytepusher** says in their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47424780/how-to-check-if-an-object-exists#comment81805061_47424780), to use `$url->has_recognized_scheme` to determine whether the string is a recognisable URI. The
[current specification for a URI](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt)
is very flexible. Most of the parts are optional, and the only mandatory part is the *scheme*.